# Android how to find resource identifier for third party apps icon

Tags: android

can we find resource identifier for  third party apps icon.Actually i want to display third party apps with there icons.

For displaying the third party app i use listview . and in adapter's getView method i use the below code `applicationInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(appNames.get(position),pm.GET_META_DATA);
imageViewAppIcon.setImageDrawable(applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm));`

and it decrease the performance of the listview.

and if i holds the drawable in the ArrayList it holds large list of Drawable(objects).any Help?

Answer (score 1):

This way you can retrieve app labels and icons for all installed apps on a phone:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);

for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : list) {
    // Retrieve the current graphical icon associated with this resolution.
    Drawable drawable = resolveInfo.loadIcon(pm);

    // Retrieve the current textual label associated with this resolution. 
    CharSequence label = resolveInfo.loadLabel(pm);
}
```

You could use the label to find the appropriate app. However, it's probably better to better to add the full class name to the search intent.

If the app isn't installed on the phone and it's only available in the market, check the [android-market-api](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/).

If you want to get other resources from third party apps check out `getResourcesForApplication`:

```
String packageName = "com.example.app";
Resources res = context.getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(packageName);
```

Comment: There is No method in Resources class that provide the application Icon's resource ID.

Comment: As long as you only want to get the app icon, you can use the `ResolveInfo`. No need for the app icons resource ID.

Comment: DId anyone got the IDs with success? Drawable works, but I am having trouble with the resource ids.